# How to install a Linux Rails gem on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, linux, rubygems

I need to upload vendorize a gem which is causing problems at my host - in this case nokogiri. My host is using linux, my development system is windows. The gem contains binaries and so my local gem downloads the win32 binaries. Is there any way I can get gem to download the linux binaries, so I can vendorize and upload them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to build the Linux version of a gem on Windows. That's why there are multiple platform versions for some gems.

You could download the original source of the Linux version, then simply store that in your repository, if you really want to have a copy of it with your app.

Or you could do all your development in a Linux virtual machine in your Windows box - then you'd have no vendoring problems.

Other than that, don't think you can do it.

Comment: My hosting company vendorised the gem on the server for me and I can download that to my source control.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command

```
gem install YOUR_GEM_NAME --platform=mswin32
```

example

```
gem install hpricot --platform=mswin32
```